# How can Discoverer get the acknowledgement from the Advertiser when the data is transferred completely using Google's Nearby Connections API?

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I am working on an app where my requirement is to transfer some files from one device to another. I am using Google's Nearby Connections API for this. As per the app requirement, when the advertiser (Receiver) receives the complete data, I need to send an acknowledegment to the Discoverer (Sender) in order to perform some operations on it. So can someone guide me through how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to be notified when the advertiser received the data you sent, you can use the callback onPayloadTransferUpdate which works like a notification/acknowledgement about a payload transfer. You can do something like this:

```
private PayloadCallback payloadCallback =
            new PayloadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPayloadReceived(@NonNull String endpointId, @NonNull Payload payload) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPayloadTransferUpdate(@NonNull String endpointId, @NonNull PayloadTransferUpdate payloadTransferUpdate) {
                    if (payloadTransferUpdate.getStatus() == PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.SUCCESS) {
                        // handle payload transfer success event - ACK
                    } else if (payloadTransferUpdate.getStatus() == PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.FAILURE) {
                        // handle payload transfer fail event - NAK
                    } else {
                        // handle other events like CANCELED and IN_PROGRESS
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: I tried that too earlier, but I am sending multiple files from one device to another,  and onPayloadTransferUpdate() gets called multiple times. I want to notify the sender when the receiver receives all the files which I guess is not supported by Nearby Connections API.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, that is not supported by Nearby Connections. What you could do is count how many messages you send and for how many messages you trigger onPayloadTransferUpdate with a SUCCESS status. When those 2 counter values are equal, you can notify the sender that all the files were received by the advertiser.

Comment: @ Catalin Mares, sorry for the late reply, I used the counting logic and it currently works at the sender side and I can proceed further with it.